How I can isolate the created resources in multiple module imports?
I make my own terraform module that creates an EC-2 instance and a role for it:
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
    ami=var.ami
    instance_type="t3a.micro"
    key_name = var.ssh_key
    iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_profile.name

    root_block_device {
        volume_size = 30
        volume_type = "gp3"
    }

    vpc_security_group_ids=var.ec2_security_groups

    # Ommitted for verbosity reduction
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "domain" {
  zone_id = var.domain_zone
  name    = local.domain
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [var.lb.dns_name]
}

# Load Balance

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "tg" {
  name     = "${local.name_with_env}-Tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type="instance"
  vpc_id=var.lb_tg_vpc
} 

This is located into a module named ec2_lb in my terraform project having the following file structure:
- modules
-- ec2_lb
--- main.tf <<< File above
- client1
-- main.tf
- client2
-- main.tf

Upon each client (clientX/main.tf) I want to create 2 ec2 instances one for production and one for staging:
module "test_staging_ec2_lb" {
  source = "../modules/ec2_lb"

 
  # Stuff ommitted for simplicity
}

module "test_production_ec2_lb" {
  source = "../modules/ec2_lb"

 
  # Stuff ommitted for simplicity
}


But I feel like the module import test_production_ec2_lb will replace the created resources created from test_staging_ec2_lb one. Is there a way to namespace it without resorting into creating duplicate folders per customer and per environment:
- modules
-- ec2_lb
--- main.tf <<< File above
- client1_production
-- main.tf
- client1_staging
-- main.tf
- client2_production
-- main.tf
- client2_staging
-- main.tf




First, instead of writing your own terraform module, see if you can re-use https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance or at least use a reference of how this module is written; this will save you a ton of effort. It has some examples that could help you to figure out how to use it.
Second, for namespacing in terraform try using workspaces. You can get an introduction to this feature via https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-workspaces (I've found this article via a simple Google search).

Consider exploring https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/examples for more.
